# Two derivative problems. Stuck on finding the normal line.

Tags: calculus

I have two problems. One is finding the second derivative. The other is finding an intersection of a normal line and an ellipsis.

1. Find $y''$
   $$ x^2 + 4y^2 = 4$$

$$y' = 2x +4 \cdot 2y \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$2x + 8y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$8y \frac{dy}{dx} = -2x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2x}{8y} = \frac{-x}{4y}$$
$$ y'' = \frac{-4y - (-x \cdot 4 \frac{dy}{dx}}{16y^2}$$

$$ \frac{-4y + (4x\frac{dy}{dx})}{16y^2}$$

$$\frac{-4y + \frac{-4x^2}{4y}}{16y^2}$$

Now I'm stuck. I feel like I can simplify more?

2. Find an additional intersection point of the ellipsis with the normal line at (-1,1).

$$x^2 - xy + y^2 = 3$$
$$2x - x\frac{dy}{dx} + y + 2y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - 2y \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = 2x + y$$
$$2x + y = \frac{dy}{dx} (x - 2y)$$
$$\frac{2x + y}{x - 2y} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

So at (-1,1) the slope is $\frac{1}{3}$

So the slope of the normal is -3. But where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify

$y'' = \frac{-4y + \frac{-4x^2}{4y}}{16y^2} = \frac{-4y^2 -x^2}{16y^3}$

In 2) you have a sign flipped in your calculation of $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {2x-y}{x-2y}$

at $(-1,1)$ the slope the tanget equals $1$ and the slope of the normal $= -1$

your line $(y-1) = -(x+1)$

Comment: do I have it flipped? show me?

Comment: You should have $2x - x\frac{dy}{dx} - y + 2y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

Comment: so what's another intersection point with the ellipsis?

Answer (score 0):

for the first derivative we get
$$2x+8yy'=0$$ or $$y'=-\frac{x}{4y}$$
computing the derivative of the equation $$2x+8yy'=0$$ once more with respect to $x$ we get:
and the second derivative
$$2+8y'^2+8yy''=0$$
solve this for $y''$ and plug in the formula for $y'$
for #2) we get
$$y=-3x+n$$ with $x=-1,y=1$ we can compute $n$
$n$ stands for the y-intercept of the linear function $$y=mx+n$$

Comment: can you show a bit more work from the first derivative to the second? I'm having trouble seeing it

Comment: where does n come from?